# python regular expression pattern with string format

Tags: python, regex

I want to do something like:

```py
re.match(r'\d{3} {}'.format('test'), '123 test')
```

However it doesn't work.

I'm only able to do regular string as patter and to escape many re characters, like:

```py
re.match('\\d{{3}} {}'.format('test'), '123 test')
```

Is there a way I can keep using r'' pattern but also do formatting string?

Comment: What's wrong with `r'\d{3} test'` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format raw string with different expressions inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754594/how-to-format-raw-string-with-different-expressions-inside)

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything useful. (If it worked, you wouldn't be asking a question.)

Comment: The raw string (`r'\d{3} {}'`) doesn't work because it needs to be (`r'\d{{3}} {}'`). `{{` isn't an escape.