# Python string format

Tags: python, string, format, filepath

I have defined the string variable

```
value=“c:/program files/tm su/usr”
```

I need to use this variable in another string like

```
Bashcmd=“Override project={value}”
```

I tried adding the rf option like this

```
Bashcmd =rf“Override {value}”
```

But it’s printing only until c:/program, white spaces are neglected.
Is there any way to use entire path in Bashcmd and can’t remove spaces in directory path because many system share same paths.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format raw string with different expressions inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754594/how-to-format-raw-string-with-different-expressions-inside)

Comment: Refer last answer in the above post, try``Bashcmd = fr“Override {value}”``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format strings like this:

```
value="c:/program files/tm su/usr"
Bashcmd=f"Override project=\"{value}\""
```

or you can simply concatenate the string like this:

```
Bashcmd="Override project=\""+value+"\""
```

Comment: My question was little different,made mistake white editing.I need to pass arguments like project which includes the path of the some folder while executing bash command like project={value} as in my recent edits